# Batch delete files older then 7 days using forfiles

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Firstly, apologies for my lack of knowledge in this area. I have been using a basic forfiles batch and have made some changes but I can't get the script to delete the folders also. Currently it works fine to delete all of the files, including files in subfolders but leaves the folders empty.

E.g. there are files and folders created in the Projects folder "C:\Files\Projects\" example:

C:\Files\Projects\1\random.txt

C:\Files\Projects\2\test\hello.xlsx

How can I include to delete the folders in addition to the files, in the top directory and subfolders?

My current script which outputs the deleted files to a log file:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Files\Projects" /s /m *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del /q /s @path" >> C:\Script\Deleted.log
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `del` command does not delete folders.

To delete folders you need to use the `rmdir` (or `rd`) command.

Do you want to delete all empty folders or only folders that you've just deleted files from? In the first case you can use:

A simpler way, or rather trick, than `rd` with a loop etc. would be to use the `robocopy` command. What you will do is basically move the whole parent folder to itself, but adding the `/S` switch that will leave out empty folders, effectively deleting them:

```
Robocopy C:\Files\Projects C:\Files\Projects /S /Move
```

Together with your file-deleting command that would be:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Files\Projects" /s /m *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del /q /s @path" >> C:\Script\Deleted.log && Robocopy C:\Files\Projects C:\Files\Projects /S /Move >> C:\Script\Deleted.log
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know about the rd or rmdir commands. I simply changed 'del' to rmdir or rd and it works perfectly!

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, you were referring to why/how `robocopy` would work here? Added.

Comment: `/S` *copies* folders but not empty ones, and `/Move` deletes all matching from the source (including the empty ones).

Comment: `robocopy ... ... /E /MOVE` seems to do the same, to remove empty folders (quite unexpectedly, in my opinion)...

Answer (score 1):

As already said, the [`del` command](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html) (also `erase`) only deletes files; to remove directories use the [`rd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) (also `rmdir`).

[`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) features a variable named `@isdir` to indicate whether the currently iterated item is a directory (value `TRUE`) or a file (value `FALSE`), so let us make use of this:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "C:\Files\Projects" /M * /D -7 /C "cmd /C if @isdir == TRUE (rd /S /Q @path) else (del /F /A @path)" >> "C:\Script\Deleted.log"
```

You may want to force deletion of read-only files (`del /F`) and to also delete hidden files (`del /A`).

Note that I changed the file mask from `*.*` to `*`, because `forfiles` would not match files with no extension with the former, since it treats [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) differently than most `cmd`-internal commands.